# "Lyrics to a song" vs. "lyrics of a song"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

I've seen both being used interchangeably. Are both valid? Is only one correct?

> 1. Lyrics **to** a song.
> 2. Lyrics **of** a song.

Comment: Surely you put lyrics to music to make a song. Therefore, lyrics and music make a song.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [Google NGram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=lyrics+of+a+song%2Clyrics+to+a+song&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) indicates that both are in use, with "lyrics of a song" being more popular:

http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=lyrics%20of%20a%20song%2Clyrics%20to%20a%20song&corpus=0&smoothing=3&year_start=1900&year_end=2000

This phrasing may be more popular because "lyrics" is a property of a "song". That is a song *has* lyrics, so the lyrics are *of a* song because this is the possessive form. I think that both are sufficiently valid (as NGrams records use from a corpus of written material, which tends to be slightly more grammar-conscious than online works such as a blog), so you could use either and be understood.

Comment: First of all, nice graph but, does the frequency of usage have a relationship to correctness?

Comment: Yes, it does. For example, ngram graphs.

Answer (score 10):

This is personal feeling, but I'd just like to say that:

"Lyrics of a song" is more correct. We usually say "words of a book", "works of an author", etc.   That's because you're asking for something that *belongs* to another, therefore "of" should be used.

"Lyrics to a song" is correct in its own way, but shouldn't be used when asking for the words of a song. "Lyrics to a song" should only be used when referring to someone giving words to a song:

> John put lyrics *to* the song.

That's personal opinion, and I don't really have any sources or links or rules to back me up. Maybe someone else has.

Comment: I'd back it up.