# Do you say "the lyrics of the song" or "the lyrics to the song"? And why?

Tags: prepositions

Well, the title says it all:

Do you say "the lyrics of the song" or "the lyrics to the song"?

Is any of these wrong?

And why?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/68062/18655, http://english.stackexchange.com/q/39274/18655,

Answer (score 5):

"of" is more [common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lyrics%20of%20the%20song,lyrics%20to%20the%20song&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), but both are correct..."to" is used to indicate possession, just as "of" does.

Comment: Thanks!  Could you show an example of "to" indicating possession (other than "Lyrics to") instead of purpose?  I was thinking of "fun time" = "time of fun" but not "time to fun"

Comment: From http://www.thefreedictionary.com/to : "I was looking for the top to the jar."

Comment: @Sebastián: Ah! You are asking Jeff to provide an answer **to** your question. Yet someone else may help give you the keys **to** the door of enlightenment. :^)

Comment: Thanks J.R.! So, I could say that it was you who handed me the keys **of** the door **to** enlightenment this time in your answer **of** my question, right?

Comment: (I'm asking because english is not my primary language and I don't really know what sounds awkward and what sounds right)

Comment: Many two-letter prepositions, such as of, to, and in, have more than a dozen definitions. Some of these overlap; others don't. "Send a letter **to** Jeff, **in** time for his birthday, **of** course. No interchangability there. But, after the package arrives, Jeff can wonder aloud: "What are the contents **of** the box?" or, "What are the contents **in** the box?" This can be tricky, and I doubt it will ever be explained in one simple answer, which is why we keep seeing similar questions here. That said, you used those words in your comment back to me just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Neither is incorrect; however, both "*to the song*" and "*of the song*" get in the way of communication.

I'd prefer to read or hear "*the lyrics*", or maybe "*the song lyrics*".  Shorter, clearer, and less typing!

Comment: How would you add the name of the song to this form of the sentence?

Comment: It depends on the context. If your communication is already about a particular song, you do not need to refer to the name again. If you want to refer to a specific lyric in a specific song, you don't need to use the word "lyric" at all.

Comment: Discarding duplicate.

Comment: Sorry, I hit the wrong key and now it will not let me edit the comment. Here is what I intended to say:  Just say "the *name-of-song* lyrics".  In fact, if it is a well-known song or one you have previously introduced, the word "lyrics" should not be necessary; it would be implied by the context of your converstation or writing.

Answer (score 1):

This is an odd one.  *Words* and *lyrics* are synonyms (I can't spot a difference between *Who wrote the words?* and *Who wrote the lyrics?*, or *Learn the words* and *Learn the lyrics*—except that *lyrics* founds fancier, as you'd expect from a Greek borrowing versus a native Germanic root). Nonetheless, they do not go with the same prepositions.

With *words*, I prefer *to* over *for*:

```
The words to this song are great
? The words for this song are great
```

But with *lyrics*, I prefer *for* over *to*:

```
? The lyrics to this song are great
The lyrics for this song are great
```

My guess is, there's nothing principled here, just an *ad hoc* quirk in how English has developed.

---

A couple of other observations.  Both *words* and *lyrics* seem to go with *of* (and possibly *in*):

```
The words of this song are great
The lyrics of this song are great
```

The (dis)preference of *to* and *for* can be overridden by the verb:

```
Who put these lyrics/words to this song?
Who wrote these lyrics/words for this song?
```